# Individual components of a quaternion?

Tags: quaternions

My systems consists of a coordinate frame and a quaternion in this system represents a roll (about x), pitch (about y) and yaw (about z) in the form of four values (qx, qy, qz, qw).

How can I separate this quaternion, into three independent quaternions, such that one represents the roll, the other represent pitch and the third represents yaw rotations?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a question more suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/ than a programming question site.

Comment: Is there a way to transfer the Q then, since these are both stack exchange websites?

Comment: Just convert it to Euler Angels representation

Comment: I feel like there should be a operation I can perform on the quaternion itself to get its component about some axis?

Comment: "Quaternions component around some axis" has not much meaning without fixating order of applying rotations since rotations in R3 are not commutative (and quaternion multiplication too). So I think you want to decompose  your quat into `q1*q2*q3`, where q1, q2, q3 represent rotations around your fixated axis. Finding Euler Angles from you quat is a practical solution to it.

Comment: Hm, I have a defined order of applying rotations - that's rpy. 

So you think I should just convert to Euler angles and then construct individual quaternions from them? And then the product of those (in the right order) will give me the the total quaternion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should extract the Euler angles, then create 3 new quaternions and then re-combine them in the right order to arrive at the original quaternion again.

[This PDF has formulas](http://www.sedris.org/wg8home/Documents/WG80485.pdf) for converting between Euler and Quaternion manually.  The formulas work in YPR format, rather than your RPY.  Can you use them?

Here they are implemented in C:

```
/* euler_2_quaternion_ZYX */

quat->w = cos(az / 2.0f) * cos(ay / 2.0f) * cos(ax / 2.0f) + sin(az / 2.0f) * sin(ay / 2.0f) * sin(ax / 2.0f);
quat->x = cos(az / 2.0f) * cos(ay / 2.0f) * sin(ax / 2.0f) - sin(az / 2.0f) * sin(ay / 2.0f) * cos(ax / 2.0f);
quat->y = cos(az / 2.0f) * sin(ay / 2.0f) * cos(ax / 2.0f) + sin(az / 2.0f) * cos(ay / 2.0f) * sin(ax / 2.0f);
quat->z = sin(az / 2.0f) * cos(ay / 2.0f) * cos(ax / 2.0f) - cos(az / 2.0f) * sin(ay / 2.0f) * sin(ax / 2.0f);



/* quaternion_2_euler_ZYX */

float qx, qy, qz, qw;

qw = quat->w;
qx = quat->x;
qy = quat->y;
qz = quat->z;

*az = atan2(qy * qz + qw * qx, 0.5f - ((qx * qx) + (qy * qy)));
*ay = asin(-2.0f * ((qx * qz) - (qw * qy)));
*ax = atan2(((qx * qy) + (qw * qz)), 0.5f - ((qy * qy) + (qz * qz)));
```